# How to get username from url on index page

Tags: php, url

i want to get username on index page, for example if url is
`https://bonusbits.cf/any_name`
i want to get "any_name" and show his status.
but whenever i tried it shows error "The requested URL was not found on this server".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this

.htaccess file

```
# Not for real file or directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

then in the PHP file

```
 $link = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
 $path = explode('/',$link);
 echo $name = end($path);
```

Comment: its works with a particular path or page name. but not on index page to get url and username.

Comment: I've updated the answer can you try the same. if its working

Comment: with ```$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];``` its showing "index.php in output" but with ```$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];``` it shows username from url.